# VB.Net - The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Tags: vb.net, request

Sometimes I have a problem with some sites

Get the next error

> The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

This is my code :

```
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
Imports System.Net.CookieContainer
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Imports System.Web
Public Class Form1
Dim cc As New CookieContainer
Dim Request As HttpWebRequest
Dim Response As HttpWebResponse
Dim Regex As String

Public Function GetResponse(ByVal url As String, ByVal referer As String) As 
String
Request = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
Request.CookieContainer = cc
If referer <> "" Then
Request.Referer = referer
End If
Response = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)


Return New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()

End Function
Public Function GetResponse(ByVal url As String, ByVal Post As String, ByVal 
Referer As String) As String
Request = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create(url), HttpWebRequest)
CType(Request, HttpWebRequest).UserAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows 
NT 6.1; en-GB; rv:1.9.1.2) Gecko/20090729 Firefox/3.5.2 (.NET CLR 
3.5.30729)"
Request.Method = "POST"

Request.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptEncoding, "gzip, deflate")
    Request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, "en-us")
    Request.CookieContainer = cc

    Request.UserAgent = ""
    If Referer <> "" Then
        Request.Referer = Referer
    End If
    Dim Bytes() As Byte = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(Post)
    Request.ContentLength = Bytes.Length
    Dim dataStream As Stream = Request.GetRequestStream()
    dataStream.Write(Bytes, 0, Bytes.Length)
    dataStream.Close()
    Response = CType(Request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    Return New StreamReader(Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()
End Function
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim html As String = GetResponse("https://temp-mail.org/option/change/", "")

    Regex = New Regex("csrf..value..(.*?)""").Match(html).Groups(1).Value
    TextBox1.Text = Regex

End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    Dim html As String
    Dim SB As New StringBuilder
    SB.Append("csrf=" & Regex)
    SB.Append("&mail=" & "Almane")
    SB.Append("&domain=" & "%40ipdeer.com")
    html = GetResponse("https://temp-mail.org/option/change/", SB.ToString, "https://temp-mail.org/option/change/")
    WebBrowser1.DocumentText = html
    TextBox2.Text = html
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

Target Site : Temp-mail.org

Error Text : The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden

Error Image :
[image: Image Error]

Answer (score 0):

It means the status code of HTTP request is 403.This Error occurs when you try to get a forbidden page or you don't set some required HTTP headers.
As I see,The page isn't forbidden.Headers may be wrong.I think you don't send Post parameters correctly.Your Request must be like this one:

```html
<p>POST /en/option/change/ HTTP/1.1<br />Host: temp-mail.org<br />User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0<br />Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8<br />Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5<br />Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br<br />Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded<br />Content-Length: 74<br />Referer: https://temp-mail.org/option/change/<br />Cookie: ezds=ffid%3D1%2Cw%3D1280%2Ch%3D720; ezohw=w%3D1280%2Ch%3D611; ezux_et_30309=0; ezux_tos_30309=2; __cfduid=d94864427a567d8e000c8ea19d00d49a21500592655; ezouid_30309=1643510745; active_template::30309=pub_site; csrf=958f27ff85864889436f0dbdab5c7f5e; mail=hakeres%40vektik.com; lang=en; __utma=185747500.940605442.1500617897.1500617897.1500617897.1; __utmb=185747500.0.10.1500617897; __utmc=185747500; __utmz=185747500.1500617897.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); ezosuigeneris=d5e4da1240ca74a2806dd4bdd53584b4; _ga=GA1.2.940605442.1500617897; _gid=GA1.2.343624442.1500617899; __qca=P0-1675212700-1500617911610; _gat=1<br />Connection: keep-alive<br />Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1<br /><br />csrf=958f27ff85864889436f0dbdab5c7f5e&amp;mail=LoginTest&amp;domain=@bestvpn.top</p>
```

The form is protected against CSRF attacks by using tokens.

You have to set Cookies & csrf token correctly.
If I have mistakes,I'm sorry for my bad English.

Comment: I also have bad English
But many solutions have been tried without a result